# How to debug with xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin

I need to debug with xamarin.android using Log.debug in that way:

```
Log.Debug(TAG, "action done");
```

But I dont know where to visualise the Log file. I am new with xamarin.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/android_debug_log/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use View > Other Windows > Android Device Logging.

An example output is shown [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/android_debug_log/)!